# QComboBox frame changing when there is background-color

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

```
self.setStyleSheet("background-color:#396745")
self.drop=QComboBox(self)
self.drop.addItem('1')
self.drop.addItem('2')
```

The output of above code
image:

[image]

The expected output is this image:

[image]

but with background color

Answer (score 0):

The problem was coming from `self`(QMainWindow)
For overcome this I changed stylesheet with `("QMainWindow{background-color:#396745}")`

Comment: Either your question was not clear, or this answer isn't. Using selectors is usually better, but, based on the code you gave in your question, the stylesheet above doesn't change that much, and the only difference is the frame color of the combobox. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @musicamante Basically I want background to be color but when background color was set to mainwindow the combobox frame get changed so how i can give color to background without changing the combobox frame that was my question

Comment: Ok, so the question was about the *frame* of the combobox. Please try to be more clear in the future, because from your question the most noticeable difference was the blue *focus* background.